# how does the OR operator (|) works in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Want to use the or operator(|) within a regular expression match but its not working. Getting error message as "unsupported operand". Can someone please have a look at it here?

Even tried both | and "or" but both didn't work.

```
import re

date = "02.29.2001"
date29 = "((02)\.(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]))"
date28 = "((02)\.(0[1-9]|[12][0-8]))"
res = re.search((date28 | date29)+("\.(\d+)"),date)
```

Here if I use only date29 then it matches but when I changed it to as above , it didn't match.

Comment: Did you try `date28+"|"+date29`?

Comment: What you can do is combine `date28 + "|" + date29` to build your search regex. What part are you trying to search with this `+("\.(\d+)")`??. I also recomend you to use a sandbox online just to build your regex beforehand such as [this one](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Python syntax (the `or` boolean and `|` bitwise OR operators) with regex syntax.

While regular expressions do use `|` to separate alternate patterns, the syntax used in regular expressions is *distinct and separate* from Python operators. You can't arbitrarily combine the two. Regular expression syntax is passed to the `re` module functions via strings, not as Python expressions.

This works:

```
either = r"({}|{})\.(\d+)".format(date28, date29)
res = re.search(either, date)
```

because the regular expression pattern is combined into a single string using regular expression syntax *first*.

Note that there is *no point* in using `date28` here, because everything that `date28` can match, can also be matched by `date29`. Moreover, `date28` won't match `02.19.`, a valid date in February.

If you want to construct a regex from 'labelled' components, I recommend you use the `re.VERBOSE` flag, which causes whitespace in a regex (including newlines) to be ignored, and adds support for using `# ...` comments. To match whitespace, use explicit classes such as `[ ]`, `[\n]`, `\s`, etc. I often combine this with explicit group names too.

E.g. your expression could be written out as:

```
february_date = re.compile(
    r"""
    (
        02\.     # month, always February
        (        # Leap year
            0[1-9]      # first 9 days
            |
            [12][0-9]   # remainder from 10 to 29
        )
        |
        02\.
        (        # regular year
            0[1-9]      # first 9 days
            |
            [12][0-8]   # remainder 10-18, 20-28
        )
    )
    \.(\d+)   # The year
    """, flags=re.VERBOSE)
res = february_date.search(date)
```

This format also makes it much easier to see that you are matching `02\.` at the start in either pattern, which is rather redundant, and the above pattern of course still has the issue with `[12][0-8]` both being redundant against `[12][0-9]` and not actually matching the 19th of February.

Personally, I'd just use `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` and then use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to validate that the matched text is actually a valid date. Building a regex to validate dates is a mammoth task, and simply not worth the effort.

For example, the pattern you tried to construct doesn't tell you that 2001 was not a leap year, so `02.29.2001` is not a valid date. But trying to parse it using `datetime.strptime()` throws an exception, telling you this isn't a valid date:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = '02.29.2001'
>>> datetime.strptime(date, "%m.%d.%Y")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 458, in _strptime
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```